# Polynomial equation involving $\cos(x)$

Tags: polynomials, functional-equations

After some chitchat I stumbled upon the following problem

> What are the real valued-polynomials $p$ verifying
>   $$\cos(p(x))=p(\cos(x))$$

My findings :

,  $p(x)=x$ works

But besides this one, I cannot find any, any clues ?

Thanks for the help,

T.D

Comment: Yup, found this one too! Is there a general form for all of them though?

Comment: $p(x)=0$ fails since
$$\cos(p(x))=\cos 0=1$$
while
$$p(\cos x)=0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$p(\cos(x))$$ is a periodic function of period $2\pi$. But $$\cos(p(x))$$ is aperiodic unless $p$ is a linear function of $x$.

Now

$$a\cos(x)+b=\cos(ax+b)$$

is only possible with $a=1,b=0$ because the LHS alternates between $a+b$ and $a-b$, which must match $1,-1$.

Anyway, another option exists, when $a=0$ (so that the RHS does not alternate), with

$$b=\cos(b),$$ which has a single real solution $b=0.7390851332152\cdots$.

Comment: why is it aperiodic ?

Comment: Because the solutions of $p(x)=2k\pi$ are not equidistant, unless $p$ is linear.